# How to mock private method in public method in Spring Boot with JUnit

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I'd like you ask a few questions and ask you for advice:

I want to test my public method (I use Spring Boot, Mockito, JUnit):

```
@Service
public class MyClass{

public Long getClientId(List<String> nameSurname) throws AuthorizationException {
        Long operatorId;
        if(...){
        (... something not interesting ...)
            User user = getUserByLogin("AnthonyGates2");
            operatorId = nonNull(user) ? user.getOperatorId() : null;
        } else {
            List<User> users = getUserListByLogin("AnthinyGates");
            operatorId = isNotEmpty(users) ? return operatorId;
         return operatorId;
    }
```

How to test the method `getClientId`?

Methods `getUserByLogin` and `getUserListByLogin` are private in this class (`MyClass`) but I have to mock the results of these private methods because these methods retrieve data from an external service.
These private methods looks like:

```
User user = DelegateImpl.getDelegate().getUserByLogin(nameAndSurname);
```

DelegateImpl.getDelegate().getUserByLogin get data from database and that data have to be mocked like:

```
when(DelegateImpl.getDelegate().getUserByLogin(any())).thenReturn(user);
```

How can I test my public class? Should I use PowerMock/PowerMockito? Making these methods public is in my opinion ugly because these methods are called only in `MyClass`. I can't find a good tutorial in Internet for my case (Spring Boot, Mockito, JUnit).

Thank you very much for all your tips!

Best regards
Matthew

Comment: Don't mock your private methods, mock the external service they use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not able to unit test a method/class then it most probably means that it just does too much. Try extracting your private methods to a separate class. It does not need to be public - you can e.g. have it package-local in the same package.

Later, in the test, you would have to inject a mock of this class and simulate its behaviour.

The setup of MyClass in its unit test could look similar to this:

```
AnotherClass anotherClassMock = Mockito.mock(AnotherClass.class);
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(anotherClassMock);
```

Where AnotherClass would have methods getUserListByLogin and getUserByLogin.

EDIT: 
It seems that the logic within in your private methods already call an external class. The problem is that you obtain an instance of an object via a call to a static `getDelegate()` method in another class.

Here's what you can do:

- Create a new field in `MyClass` which would have the same type as the one returned by `getDelegate()` method (I don't know what that is, I'll call it `Delegate`)
- Have 2 constructors: a default one which would assign the result of `getDelegate` method to your new field and another one which would take an instance of `Delegate` as a parameter and assign it to your field
- In tests use the second constructor to create an instance of `MyClass` and pass a mock of `Delegate` class

It would look more ore less like this:

```
class MyClass() {
    private Delegate delegate;

    MyClass() {
        this.delegate = DelegateImpl.getDelegate();
    }

    MyClass(Delegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    // ... the rest
}
```

Comment: My 2 private methods are very small, they look like: return DelegateImpl.getDelegate().getUserByLogin(nameAndSurname); and nothing more.

Comment: I've edited my answer with another proposition. Please, see if it helps.

Comment: Don't call static methods to resolve other dependencies (DelegateImpl.getDelegate() is static call) .That makes testing really hard. Use dependency injection via the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Test the unit only by calling the public methods. I think that your example is a class in the service layer (contains business logic) and the two getUser... methods should be in a different class (I think in the data layer) where they can be public. Inject that class via the constructor as a dependency (in the service object) so you can mock it when testing the service class. The data layer class (with the getUser... methods) can also be tested by it's own unit tests.

Comment: MyClass is MyClassService and has just more public one-line methods very similar to my two private methods (call an external service) like public void saveUser(User user) {DelegateImpl.getDelegate().saveUser(user);}

Comment: Or maybe should I make these methods protected? And then use Mockito? Or maybe the best option would be to add my private methods to the MyClassService and change these to public and the whole logic move to the other class so in MyClassService should be only public methods that call external service...

Comment: If that two method contain business logic you could move them to for example a UserService class where they can be public and you write a UserServiceTest class.  Pass the UserService into a ClientLoginService (or something similar) where the getClientId is implemented. If testing is hard than your design is incorrect (abstraction problems and/or static calls)

Comment: Yes - thanks to You I understood that we can refactor our code when we can't mock and should test private methods. So I removed all the logic from MyClass and leaved only public methods that call external service. And I moved my public method getClientId to another class that uses my public methods from MyClass. This way I can easily use Mockito. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Happy to hear about successful refactoring! :)